# How to change datetime in xml response using Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm using Rails 3.0.4, Ruby 1.9.2p0 on a Mac machine. While using Sqlite as the default database and successfully added respond_to :xml functionality, I see the datetime format in the xml is something like:

```
<updated-at type="datetime">2011-03-20T12:15:47Z</updated-at>
```

While there're several posts on the web (also here) asking how to change the date/time format like using configuration in config/locale/en.yml, or add

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

in the initializer file, neither work.

I think the problem is because when I call someobj.to_xml, for the datetime objects, rails will call

```
datetime.xmlschema
```

instead of calling

```
datetime.to_s
```

which bypass the settings mentioned above.
Although I know this may be the culprit, I don't know how to fix it. Anyone has experience on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: As datetime formats are set as part of the XML standard (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats) You had better not change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need to change it you can override the xmlschema method instead of the to_s

```
class DateTime
  def xmlschema
    strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  end
end
```

But as I said in the comment you are breaking the XLM standard and application connecting to yours will not expect this datetime format.

Comment: Yup, I thought it could be done via override the original xmlschema method and I added this code in the config/environment.rb file but still no luck -- I'm sure it got replaced. In the rails console, I can see the output of "DateTime.now.xmlschema" is "2011-03-21 07:34:00" already but in the xml, still  "2011-03-21T07:34:00Z"

Comment: You can try putting it in an initializer. Or you can directly override the to_xml as specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403794/xml-serialization-is-not-including-milliseconds-in-datetime-field-from-rails-mode

Answer (score 1):

I put this code into time_formats.rb in initializers to get milliseconds

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  alias_method :original_xmlschema , :xmlschema
  def xmlschema(fraction_digits = 3)
    original_xmlschema(fraction_digits)
  end
end
```

[Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/988848)